how to exactly equate ggplot and gganimate images
I am using ggplot2 and gganimate to create a slide deck of figures, some of which are static and some of which are animated. I wish to create the impression of a continuous "animation" (i.e., stepping through the static images and animations) by creating the same images with ggplot2 and gganimate that "build up".
This is mostly straightforward.
Problem
However, there are subtle differences between the ggplot2 and gganimate figures: the spacing between the axes and labels is slightly different, as is the hight of the plotting area. This causes a "jumping" visual effect when moving from slide to slide (see the left side of the graph and the bottom for where the effect is strongest).

Question
Why are the ggplot2 and gganimate versions of these images slightly different, and how can I get them to be the same so I don't get the "jumping" effect when I move from one to the other?
Reproducing the problem
Consider the following code that create an initial gg ggplot that contains just the plotting area (no line):
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(magick)

## Setup
res = 300
w = 7
h = 4

## Create ggplot
data.frame(
  x = seq(-1,1,length.out=128),
  y = seq(-1,1,length.out=128)^2
)|>
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  coord_cartesian(
    xlim = c(-1,1),
    ylim = c(0,1),
    expand = TRUE
    ) +
  geom_line(
    alpha=0 # Add invisible line to make sure plots contain same elements
    ) -> gg

I then create the initial image in two ways: using ggsave, and using the ragg_png device directly (as gganimate does internally as best aas I can tell; see https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/blob/b46d1ff9bfee89c33ca8d6c4fd3fa1074c649027/R/animate.R#L297)
# Write png using ggsave
ggsave(plot = gg, filename = 'ggsave.png', device = ragg::agg_png, 
       dpi = res, width = w*res, height = h*res, units = 'px')

# Write png using device, as gganimate does internally
ragg::agg_png(filename = 'dev.png',res = res, width = w*res, height = h*res,units = 'px', background = "white")
gg
dev.off()

As it turns out, these two images are identical, both visually and according to their md5sum.
tools::md5sum('ggsave.png')
#                         ggsave.png 
# "fa1b4f40ae7d2705e320f8b60d71fda6" 
tools::md5sum('dev.png')
#                            dev.png 
# "fa1b4f40ae7d2705e320f8b60d71fda6" 


One of these would be the initial static slide which looks like this:

Then, I would transition to the animation:
gg + 
  geom_line() +
  transition_reveal(x) -> anim

anim_save(
  filename = 'gganim_save.gif', animation = anim, nframes = 10,
  device = 'ragg_png', res = res, width = w*res, height = h*res, units = 'px',
  renderer = gifski_renderer()
  )


The resulting animation looks like this:

It isn't immediately obvious, but the image is slightly different: the plotting area is slightly bigger in the gganimate version, and the axis text is slightly closer to the ticks. I can both confirm this is true, and not due to the GIF creation, by using gganimate's file_renderer, which outputs the individual PNGs. I then create an animated GIF to show the two images one after another, which shows the effect of moving from slide to slide:
td = tempdir()

# This will cause an error, but it is ok because we don't care
# about creating the animation, just outputting the individual
# PNG files

anim_save(
  animation = anim, nframes = 10,
  device = 'ragg_png', res = res, width = w*res, height = h*res, units = 'px',
  renderer = file_renderer(dir = td, prefix = 'gganim_file', overwrite = TRUE)
)

# Copy the first slide of the animation to the current folder
file.copy(file.path(td, "gganim_file0001.png"), to = '.', overwrite = TRUE)

# Get the information about the three PNGs
dir(pattern = '*.png') |>
  lapply(\(fn){
    img <- image_read(fn)
    inf <- image_info(img)
    inf$fn = fn
    inf
  }) |>
  do.call(args = _, what='rbind')
## A tibble: 3 × 8
#  format width height colorspace matte filesize density fn                 
#  <chr>  <int>  <int> <chr>      <lgl>    <int> <chr>   <chr>              
#1 PNG     2100   1200 sRGB       FALSE    27163 118x118 dev.png            
#2 PNG     2100   1200 sRGB       FALSE    31499 118x118 gganim_file0001.png
#3 PNG     2100   1200 sRGB       FALSE    27163 118x118 ggsave.png       

I used the exact same device settings to create the gganimate file. They are the same dimension and density.
I can use now use gifski to create the animation at the beginning of this question:
gifski::gifski(c('dev.png','gganim_file0001.png'),gif_file = 'compare.gif',
               loop = TRUE, width = res*w, height = res*h)


Possible clues
Poking around in the gganimate code, I found that the creation of the files for the individual frames appears to be here: https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/blob/b46d1ff9bfee89c33ca8d6c4fd3fa1074c649027/R/animate.R#L300
The device is opened in line 297. But args does not appear to contain any of the device arguments I set; all information about the image appears to be contained in the plot object, which I don't get. There's something subtly different going on than my use of ragg::agg_png() and dev.off() above. I just don't know what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Session info:
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.7

Locale: en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / C / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8

Package version:
  class_7.3.22       classInt_0.4.10    cli_3.6.3          colorspace_2.1-1   compiler_4.3.2    
  cpp11_0.5.0        crayon_1.5.3       curl_5.2.3         DBI_1.2.3          e1071_1.7.16      
  fansi_1.0.6        farver_2.1.2       gganimate_1.0.9    ggplot2_3.5.1      gifski_1.32.0     
  glue_1.8.0         graphics_4.3.2     grDevices_4.3.2    grid_4.3.2         gtable_0.3.5      
  hms_1.1.3          isoband_0.2.7      KernSmooth_2.23.24 labeling_0.4.3     lattice_0.22.6    
  lifecycle_1.0.4    lpSolve_5.6.21     magick_2.8.5       magrittr_2.0.3     MASS_7.3.60.0.1   
  Matrix_1.6.5       methods_4.3.2      mgcv_1.9.1         munsell_0.5.1      nlme_3.1.166      
  pillar_1.9.0       pkgconfig_2.0.3    prettyunits_1.2.0  progress_1.2.3     proxy_0.4.27      
  R6_2.5.1           ragg_1.3.3         RColorBrewer_1.1.3 Rcpp_1.0.13        renv_1.0.10       
  rlang_1.1.4        s2_1.1.7           scales_1.3.0       sf_1.0.17          splines_4.3.2     
  stats_4.3.2        stringi_1.8.4      systemfonts_1.1.0  textshaping_0.4.0  tibble_3.2.1      
  tools_4.3.2        transformr_0.1.5   tweenr_2.0.3       units_0.8.5        utf8_1.2.4        
  utils_4.3.2        vctrs_0.6.5        viridisLite_0.4.2  withr_3.0.1        wk_0.9.3          
  xfun_0.48  


You said it jumps in the slides, have you tried to place the two side by side in any other word processor? E.g., MS Word? Google Pages? Since you've checked the most obvious elements (e.g., size, etc.), I would check the settings in the slides. For example, is there different padding added to a gif versus png in the slide?

The animated gif at the start is the two images placed on top of each other. It shows it isn't the slides, and it's not a simple matter of padding (e.g. the x label is not affected and neither is the top of the graph, but the y label is). It has something to do with internal lengths, but I don't know what.

I have spent some time going through it and I think it all comes down to the compression applied to the gif. In other words, you may need to animate the blank plot, of plot enough frames to start on a blank plot (with your question, 100 frames will start with a blank plot).

It can't be the GIF compression, because the file_renderer() to generate the "gganim_file0001.png" I used for my demo does not convert to GIF. It shows the problem occurs prior to the GIF creation. You're right that generating and using the first frame would work in some cases, but sometimes I use multiple rounds of "building up" so that's not a general solution.
